# The type or namespace name could not be found, Beginner in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reference, namespaces, kinect

Hello I'm a beginner in C# and I'm trying an online example to use the Kinect for Windows device.

I think the problem is in my referencing but don't know what to do

I think it has something to do with the .Net framework as the example seems to be based on an older version of the framework

PS: I did reference the kinect dll using "Add References"

and the project references are:

```
Microsoft.CSharp
Microsoft.Kinect
System
System.ComponentModel.Composition
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
System.Core
System.Data
System.Data.DataSetExtensions
System.Deployment
System.Drawing
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing
System.Runtime.Remoting
System.Runtime.Serialization
System.Windows.Forms
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap
System.Xml
System.Xml.Linq
```

The errors I'm getting are:

> Error 1: the type or namespace name 'Runtime' Could not be found line
>   20
>
> Error 2: the type or namespace name 'ImageFrameReadyEventArgs' Could
>   not be found line 43
>
> Error 2: the type or namespace name 'PlanarImage' Could not be found
>   line 50

here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using Microsoft.Kinect;

namespace HelloKinectWorld
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Runtime nui = Runtime.Kinects[0];


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(
        object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            nui.Initialize(RuntimeOptions.UseColor);
            nui.VideoStream.Open(
            ImageStreamType.Video,
            2,
            ImageResolution.Resolution640x480,
             ImageType.Color);
            nui.VideoFrameReady +=
            new EventHandler<ImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(
            FrameReady);
        }

        void FrameReady(object sender,
        ImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            PlanarImage Image = e.ImageFrame.Image;
            Bitmap bmap = PImageToBitmap(Image);
            pictureBox1.Image = bmap;
        }

        Bitmap PImageToBitmap(PlanarImage PImage)
        {
            Bitmap bmap = new Bitmap(
            PImage.Width,
            PImage.Height,
            PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
            BitmapData bmapdata = bmap.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, PImage.Width,
            PImage.Height),
             ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
            bmap.PixelFormat);
            IntPtr ptr = bmapdata.Scan0;
            Marshal.Copy(PImage.Bits,
            0,
            ptr,
            PImage.Width *
            PImage.BytesPerPixel *
             PImage.Height);
            bmap.UnlockBits(bmapdata);
            return bmap;
        }

        private void button1_Click(
        object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            nui.NuiCamera.ElevationAngle += 4;
        }

        private void button2_Click(
        object sender,
        EventArgs e)
        {
            nui.NuiCamera.ElevationAngle -= 4;
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(
                     object sender,
                     FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            nui.Uninitialize();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you list the project references too, as I'd guess you could be missing one of those.

Comment: if you right click the `Runtime` keyword don't you get an option to Import some libraries?

Comment: @Jon Hanna I listed the references just now

Comment: @me how It doesn't suggest anything, there is a resolve option to turn in into System.Runtime or Microsoft.Runtime but that causes another error 'Runtime' is a namespace not type

Comment: There is a name collision there I think. If you have two libraries that use the same names for their internal classes then you have to either create aliases for the namespaces or explicitly qualify the Class youre about to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of the Kinect SDK are you using? In the most recent version (**1.8**), **Runtime** would most likely be **KinectSensor,** **ImageFrameReadyEventArgs** would be **ColorFrameReadyEventArgs** (or AllFramesReadyEventArgs) and **PlanarImage** would be **ColorImage**.

Answer (score 0):

This usually means you need to add some references to assemblies. You are importing Microsoft.Kinect, but you should check that you're actually referencing the microsoft.kinect dlls from your visual studio project.

You can check it on the references folder in your visual studio project. If you haven't added the required kinect dlls as part of the project, do so by using context menu and "add reference".

Comment: I did reference the microsoft.kinect dll using the "add reference" I forgot to mention that, will do now, but that doesn't seem to be the problem